# Global fitting with shared parameters

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have about 100 datasets that needs to be fitted with the same parameters following the function y = a0 + a1 * (x - c) + a2 * (x - c)**2 + a3 * (x - c) **3. They all have the same a0, a1, a2, a3. The only difference is the variable x has a different offset c in each dataset. And these offsets are unknown.

I tried using symfit to fit 20 datasets. But when the number of datasets increase, this method gets too slow. The efficiency is determined by the symfit library.
Is there any way to do the fitting quickly? Any other library I can try?

```
num = 100 # the number of datasets
ys = variables(', '.join('y{}'.format(i) for i in range(num)))
xs = variables(', '.join('x{}'.format(i) for i in range(num)))

a0, a1, a2, a3 = parameters('a0, a1, a2, a3')
cs = parameters(', '.join('c{}'.format(i) for i in range(num)))

model_dict = {
    y: a0 + a1 * (x - c) + a2 * (x - c) ** 2 + a3 * (x - c) ** 3
    for x, y, c in zip(xs, ys, cs)
}

para_dict = {}
for n in np.arange(num):
    para_dict[str(y[n])] = x[n]  
    #x is a list of lists. Each sub-list contains the x values in one dataset
    para_dict[str(xs[n])] = y[n]

fit = Fit(model_dict, **para_dict)
```

Comment: Since, this question is related to improving efficiency of running code, it seems to me to be more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.